# Parameters of a Litz wire

Tags: litz-wire

What do these numbers tell about the Litz wire parameters? [image]

Comment: perhaps 80 strands of 0.1 mm diameter wire

Answer (score 2):

Litz wire is made up of multiple strands of wire. I assume they meant to use the diameter symbol '⌀' instead of the Greek letter Phi 'ф'. In this case it means that each strand in the conductor has a diameter of 0.1 (presumably in millimeters) and there are 80 of these strands making up the conductor.

[image]
[image]